# Android - Linearlayout inside an horizontalscrollview not working

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

i have this layout which is not working as the horizontalscrollview is not being displayed:
Basically in the first container there are two children layouts, the first is fixed and the second should scroll horizontally but the second one is not appearing.

The @drawable/disattivato contains:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
<gradient  
          android:startColor="#333333"  
     android:endColor="#000000" 
     android:type="radial"  
     android:gradientRadius="500"/>  

   <stroke
                android:dashGap="10px"
                android:dashWidth="10px"
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ababb2" />
</shape>
```

And this is my layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="8" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/backgroundbutton"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="kick11"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8pt"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            other textviews...

    </LinearLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="8" >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dip"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im11"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im12"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im13"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im14"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im15"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im16"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im17"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im18"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im19"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im110"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im111"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im112"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im113"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im114"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im115"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/im116"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/buf"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/buf1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/buf2"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/buf3"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/buf4"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/buf5"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                            </LinearLayout>
                    other linear layouts with the same exactly structure

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: i did it but still not appearing the horizontal scroll...is correct to set list of imageviews with android:layout_width="wrap_content" ?

Comment: beside the linear layout

Answer (score 1):

A basic outline for your layout follows. Pay close attention to where you're setting `wrap_content` and `match_parent` on the `View`s, as that is what was causing problems.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/backgroundbutton"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="kick11"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/im11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/im12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/disattivato"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                ...
                ...

            </LinearLayout>

            ...
            ...

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```